# Concat files by passing file name and printing file name in the final output - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a list of files which I want to combine them in a single file by passing the file name as a parameter. Also, in the final out, I want to add some hard coded text before and after the merging. For example: In a folder, I have 5 files labelled 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, 4.txt & 5.txt. 
What I want in my out is content for 1.txt, 3.txt & 5.txt and the file content be like

'1.txt Starts'

Then the content of the 1.txt

'1.txt Ends'

'3.txt Starts'

Then the content of the 3.txt

'3.txt Ends'

'5.txt Starts'

Then the content of the 5.txt

'5.txt Ends'

I am new to powershell world, and any help will be very helpfull.

Note: At any given time I can have n numbers of files to merge. In my question, I only provided an example of the output.

Comment: Why do you tag your question with [tag:batch-file] when you want a [tag:powershell] solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you a little noobish solution, but i think it will be easier to understand :)

```
$FolderWithFiles = 'C:\Users\YourUser\Desktop\FolderWithFiles\' #You can have many files here
$FilesToMerge = '1.txt', '2.txt', '5.txt'  #List only the ones you need
$OutputFile = 'C:\Users\YourUser\Desktop\FolderWithFiles\Output4.txt' #Set the output file. No need to be existing file'
$i = 0

$FileCollection = Get-ChildItem $FolderWithFiles

foreach($file in  $FileCollection) #Loop trough all files
{
    $i++ #I use it to get the current number of the file

    $CurrentFileName = $file.Name
    $CurrentFilePath = $file.FullName 

    #Check if the files are the one you need
    if($FilesToMerge -contains $CurrentFileName){

        #get their content
       $CurrentContent = Get-Content $CurrentFilePath

       #Create new content
       $NewFileContent = "`r`nFile " + $i + " Starts`r`n" + $CurrentContent + "`r`nFile " + $i + " Ended`r`n " 

       #Append it to a text file 
       $NewFileContent | Out-File -LiteralPath $OutputFile -Append
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I liked this approach but after changing #create new content to  #Create new content
       $NewFileContent = "`r`Print " + $CurrentFileName + " Starts`r`n" + $CurrentContent + "`r`Print " + Print + " Ends`r`n " , it throws error. What i want is 'Print filename Starts' then file content then 'Print filename ends'. Please help with it

Comment: You have an error in the line - you used "Print" instead $CurrentFileName for the ending. Replace the whole line with: `$NewFileContent = "'r'nPrint " + $CurrentFileName + " Starts'r'n" + $CurrentContent + "'r'nPrint " + $CurrentFileName + " Ends'r'n " `   - this works for me. :) But instead of the apostrophe use the escape sign

Comment: Is it possible to break the content of file.. As of now the whole content comes in a single line. And I do have files having huge content??

Comment: Here is what you need `$CurrentContent = Get-Content $CurrentFilePath | out-string` Just add `| out-string` :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
Function Merge-Files {
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    Param (
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -Type Leaf})]
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$File1,
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -Type Leaf})]
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$File3,
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -Type Leaf})]
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$File5,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$Destination
    )

    $ContentFile1 = Get-Content -LiteralPath $File1
    Write-Verbose "Saved content of '$File1' as '$ContentFile1'"

    $ContentFile3 = Get-Content -LiteralPath $File3
    Write-Verbose "Saved content of '$File3' as '$ContentFile3'"

    $ContentFile5 = Get-Content -LiteralPath $File5
    Write-Verbose "Saved content of '$File5' as '$ContentFile5'"

    $NewContent = @"
'1.txt Starts'
$ContentFile1
'1.txt Ends'

'3.txt Starts'
$ContentFile3
'3.txt Ends'

'5.txt Starts'
$ContentFile5
'5.txt Ends'
"@ # Needs to be against the margin

    $NewContent | Out-File -LiteralPath $Destination -Force| Out-Null
    Write-Verbose "New file '$Destination' saved with content '$NewContent'"

}

$Params = @{
    File1 = 'C:\1.txt'
    File3 = 'C:\3.txt'
    File5 = 'C:\5.txt'
    Destination = 'C:\NewFile.txt'
}

Merge-Files @Params -Verbose
# Same as writing: Merge-Files -File1 'C:\1.txt' -File3 'C:\3.txt' ..
```

Some techniques used here are:

- [ValidateScript](https://powershell.org/validatescript-for-beginners/) in the parameters
- [Splatting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts/) for addressing parameters
- [Here string](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx)

Comment: I can have n number files to merge, and in this snippet it is hardcoded to just 3.